# TextView Clicking does not cover all of TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have some text and it is stored in local database and I show them via a LISTVIEW and I made a Row for each of them to show each Status in a single Row in Lisview , and I used onListItemClick method and I want taht when each row is clicked a menu for sharing should popup till here it is correct but it just works for the top section of that row not all sections Please tell me how to make all sections of that row clickable.

Here is the class code:

```
public class sharedlist extends ListActivity {

private String[] items;
private database db;

private Typeface homa;
private Typeface nazanin;
private SharedPreferences sp;
private Typeface god;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sharedlist);


    db=new database(this);
    db.open();

    items=new String[db.Count("content")];

    homa=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/homa.ttf");
    nazanin=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/nazanin.ttf");
    god=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/Godfather.ttf");
    sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("setting", 0);

    setListAdapter(new AAD());


}



@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, db.Display_Shared(position, 2).toString());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"اشتراک گذاری از طریق"));

}

class AAD extends ArrayAdapter{

    public AAD(){
        super(sharedlist.this , R.layout.row,items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView username= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_username);
        TextView maintext= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_maintext);

        username.setText(db.Display_Shared(position,1).toString());
        maintext.setText(db.Display_Shared(position, 2).toString());

        username.setTypeface(god);

        if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("nazanin")){


            maintext.setTypeface(nazanin);


        }else if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("homa")){

            maintext.setTypeface(homa);

        }


        if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("k")){

            maintext.setTextSize(18);

        }else if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("b")){

            maintext.setTextSize(25);

        }
        return (row);
    }
}

/*@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    db.close();
}*/


}
```

and here is the row section XML file codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="نام کاربری"
    android:id="@+id/row_username"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="متن اصلی"
    android:id="@+id/row_maintext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_username"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add clickListener to your relative layout instead of just text views.

Comment: it didn't work this way too